# Android wear app with Line App Integration

Tags: android, line, wear-os

I would like to know more about the weather android wear will support the Line app or not. I've an requirement that sign-In with Line app. When I pair with the device and watch, where I could not able to see the my line app in android watch. Please suggest me the best possible solutions.

Please revert back for any clarification.

Answer (score 0):

There's no indication at http://line.me that LINE supports Android Wear. So if LINE isn't running on the watch, you'll need to build an interface with the phone, and connecct to the LINE API there.

Get started with the documentation at https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html